# API call from CURL to Node

Tags: node.js, curl

I'm working on an API that lets me test my request string online and gives me a `curl` statement (so far pretty standard).

The issue is that I can't put that curl into a Node.js code.

Here's the curl:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer <my_key_here>" "https://api.<api_name>.com/stations?limit=20&searchstring=cancun*"
```

I tried to use `Postman` to parse that url, but no success.

The company doesn't provide a module (to my knowledge) that I can call from the Node.js script.

I'm following the Node.js `requests` page for my .js file.
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

```
var request = require('request');

request({
url: 'https://api.<api_name>.com/stations',

headers: {
    'Accept': application/json,
    'Authorization: Bearer': <my_key>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'Authorization: Bearer': <my_key>`
```

does the wrong thing. The header name (and thus the property name) must be `Authorization`, and `Bearer ....` should be the value. Thus:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer <my_key_as_a_string>'
```

or

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + my_key_as_a_variable
```